# PowerShell shortest syntax to create a new PSObject using Property?

Tags: powershell, code-golf

I use the following very often:

```
New-Object psobject -Property @{a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4}
```

I would like to make this as short as possible, perhaps even 1 character?
What's the shortest way to create a new psobject using the properties above?

My desire is that I could do it with a syntax similar to this:

```
#{a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4}
```

Note that I replaced the @ with a new 'special' symbol.

Note, if this is considered off-topic, I will move it.

Comment: I suppose creating a function you could call for this from your profile is a silly excuse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PowerShell 3 and later support this syntax:

```
[pscustomobject]@{a=1; b=2; c=3; d=4}
```

One of the added benefits is that the properties are ordered, unlike a standard call to New-Object.

You add overhead, but presumably you could [create your own type accelerator](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/09/simplify-your-script-by-creating-powershell-type-accelerators.aspx) that does something similar to pscustomobject, and use a shorter name : )  Not sure what goes on under the hood of pscustomobject though.

Comment: AAHHH this was going to be my answer.... Good work. My experiment making an accelerator `$accelerators::add("o","System.Management.Automation.PSObject")` then `[o]$props` make different results. Just ended up with a hastable

Comment: Winner!  I like it, and it is straight PowerShell.  Thank you @CookieMonster!

Comment: This is an awesome accelerator.  Especially if you're looping through an array of objects and want to export custom objets to a pst. `[pscustomobject]@[a=1} | export-csv $exportfile`

Comment: Why is  [PSCustomObject]@{a=1} different from  [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]@{a=1} ?